# Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in terms of an orthonormal set

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, orthonormal

Can someone verify the consistency of my work for the solution of this exercise?

> Let $\{e_n\}$ be an orthonormal system in a linear space $X$ with inner product. Prove that, for any $x,y \in X$,
> $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|{\langle e_n,x \rangle}||{\langle{ e_n,y \rangle}}| \leq \|{x}\|\|{y}\|.$$

Here's my approach:Let $x=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\langle e_n,x \rangle e_n$ and $y=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \langle e_m,y \rangle e_m$. we have that:

$$|{\langle x, y \rangle}|= \bigg|{ \bigg\langle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \langle e_n,x \rangle e_n, \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\langle e_m,y \rangle e_m \bigg\rangle}\bigg|\\
    =\bigg|{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \langle \langle e_n,x \rangle e_n, \langle e_m,y \rangle e_m \rangle}\bigg|\\
    =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} |{\langle \langle e_n,x \rangle e_n, \langle e_m,y \rangle e_m \rangle}|\\
    =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}|{\overline{\langle e_n,x \rangle}{\langle e_m,y \rangle}{\langle e_n, e_m \rangle}}|\\
    =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}|{\overline{\langle e_n,x \rangle}{\langle e_n,y \rangle}\delta_{mn}}|\\
    =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|{\overline{\langle e_n,x \rangle}{\langle e_n,y \rangle}}|\\
    =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|{\langle e_n,x \rangle}||{\langle e_n,y \rangle }|$$

This looks right so far. Now by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $|\langle x,y \rangle | \leq \|x\|\|y\|$. But $|{\langle x, y \rangle}| = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|{\langle e_n,x \rangle}||{\langle e_n,y \rangle }| $. Therefore,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|{\langle e_n,x \rangle}||{\langle e_n,y \rangle }|  \leq \|x\|\|y\|.$$

Is this enough to solve the problem? my professor said it doesn't solve it because by the other hand:
$|\langle e_n,x \rangle| \leq \|x\|,\;|\langle e_n,y\rangle| \leq \|y\|$, so it's the case where
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|{\langle e_n,x \rangle}||{\langle e_n,y \rangle }| \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\|x\|\|y\| = \infty$$.

Comment: The absolute value of the inner product is not equal, in general to the sum of the products of absolute values of their corresponding inner products with the basis elements, so your solution is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

For every $N$, the C.S inequality implies
$$\sum_{n=1}^N|\langle e_n,x\rangle|\cdot |\langle e_n,y\rangle|\leq\left (\sum_{n=1}^N|\langle e_n,x\rangle|^2\right)^{1/2}\left (\sum_{n=1}^N|\langle e_n,y\rangle|^2\right)^{1/2}\leq \|x\|\cdot\|y\|$$
now let $N\to\infty$.

Comment: the square roots of the sums are $\leq \|x\|$ and $\leq |y\|$ respectively by Bessel's inequality, right?

Comment: Yes, indeed, it is Bessel's inequality.